# Python: creating a dictionary: {int, class object} in a loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to create a dictonary: {int, Class} in a loop, however the class object is being overriden.
I am pretty sure that this is a basic problem, but I am stuck

```
class Simple:
    simpleDic = {
        'name': {""},
        'age': {1}}

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.simpleDic['name'] = name
        self.simpleDic['age'] = age
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}\n".format(self.simpleDic['name'], self.simpleDic['age'])

def foo():
    myDict = {}
    for x in range(3):
        myDict[x] = Simple('Name' + str(x), x)
        print(('{}: {}\n'.format("Creating", myDict[x])))
    
    for key in myDict:
        print(('{}: {}\n'.format("Printing" + str(key), myDict[key])))


#### Main program here ####

foo()
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is on the last print
You're printing `myDict[x]` when you should print `myDict[key]`

x contains the last value from the first iteration, so you're practically printing the same key all over

Following your question in this comments:

```
class Simple:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.simpleDic = {"name": name, "age": age}
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}\n".format(self.simpleDic['name'], self.simpleDic['age'])
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} {}\n".format(self.simpleDic['name'], self.simpleDic['age'])    

def foo():
    myDict = {}
    for x in range(3):
        myDict[x] = Simple('Name' + str(x), x)
        print(('{}: {}\n'.format("Creating", myDict[x])))
        
    print(myDict)
```

Comment: My goodness, what a stupid mistake. I am sorry about that.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: And what if i changed the code as in question now (replaced simple variable with a dictionary):

Comment: Then it would fail, as myDict belongs to the scope of the `foo` function, and you would get a `NameError: name 'myDict' is not defined`

Comment: You can return `myDict` in the foo function, and assign it to a variable on the global scope (before your loop)

Comment: It was a copy-paste problem (corrected snippet). myDict is in a scope of foo() function.

Comment: You're problem here is different, it's inside the Simple() class.
simpleDic is in the class level, and not the instance level, it means it's sharing values across all instances.
If you'll move it to the instance level, you should be fine.
(see my updated answer)